# PMD violation : Use explicit scoping instead of the default package private level

Tags: java, pmd

I just begin to use PMD. I can't fix in my code PMD violation : "Use explicit scoping instead of the default package private level".

It appears on these places in my code:

```
String carName = ""; //car name
String carSize = ""; //car size
String carColor = "";//car color

ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList();
static MyLog log = new MyLog(); //log
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regards to explicit scoping, make your fields private to enforce encapsulation