# How to solve PMD Violation : Use explicit scoping instead of the default package private level

Tags: java, package, default, pmd, scoping

I want to fix my code **PMD violation**:

```
Use explicit scoping instead of the default package private level
```

It appears on these places in my code:

```
File saveFile = new File("C:/Upload/"); 
EmployeImplMetier dbE= new EmployeImplMetier();
DepartementImplMetier dbD = new DepartementImplMetier();
FonctionImplMetier dbF = new FonctionImplMetier();
ServiceImplMetier dbS = new ServiceImplMetier();
TypePaiementImplMetier dbT = new TypePaiementImplMetier();
ModePaiementImplMetier dbM = new ModePaiementImplMetier();
```

I found this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791038/pmd-violation-use-explicit-scoping-instead-of-the-default-package-private-leve) before but it didn't help.
Could anyone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: The question you linked contains exactly the same answer as the one you accepted here...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PMD violation : Use explicit scoping instead of the default package private level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791038/pmd-violation-use-explicit-scoping-instead-of-the-default-package-private-leve)

Comment: @codebox added that i should add getters for having access from outside but for private i know that i should have variables as a private [**not the same answer**]

Comment: "If you need to access them from outside the class in which they are declared then implement some `getXxx ` methods."

Comment: @kryger is it the same answer !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These variables should all be declared using the `private` keyword:

```
private File saveFile = new File("C:/Upload/");
```

If you need to access them from outside the class in which they are declared then implement some `getXxx` methods.